# IOS 7.1 startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. Crash when app is terminating manually

Tags: ios

I'm using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges to handle user location tracking. When I'm trying to terminate my app manually, I'm getting crash before I get applicationWillTerminate notification. If I use startUpdatingLocation instead, my app is ending without any crash and with applicationWillTerminate notification. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: I can see only "Thread 1: signal SIGKILL" message in main().

Comment: Does anything appear in the debug console?

Comment: only "(lldb)" message

Comment: That message just means the debugger is ready to accept commands.